# displaying certain languages on the left instead of the right

Tags: java, android, xml, listview, right-to-left

I am building an app that has language settings.  I am using a listview to display all of the language options.  Some languages, like Hebrew and Arabic, are placed on the right automatically because they are written from right to left.  Is there a way to force those list items to the left like the other languages?

[Here is a picture to better understand what I am talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lCBau.png)

Comment: Did my answer solve your issue? If someone's answer is a solution to your problem, you can check the green check mark on the left - which is an incentive for people like myself.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this style attribute

```
android:layoutDirection="ltr"
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/LayoutDirection.html#LTR